# MySQL table JOIN with ordering by averages

Tags: mysql, sql

First off, I am not very good with MySQL yet, so go easy on me. I am not even sure how to word my question.

I have two tables; one table contains information about links, the other ratings of each link made by users. Essentially, I just need to be able to order the links table by rating average.

TABLES:

**links**

- link_id  *PK int autoincrement*
- url  *varchar*
- title  *varchar*
- description  *text*
- rating *decimal*

**link_ratings**

- link_rating_id *PK int autoincrement*
- link_id *FK int*
- user_id *FK int*
- rating *decimal*

What I need is when someone adds a link rating to a link (new link_ratings entry) or updates their current rating, all of the ratings for that link are averaged and updated on the rating column in links. OR Can I scrap the rating column in the links table entirely and use a JOIN?

If so, how would I go about doing the JOIN. If not, how do I make TRIGGER that would accomplish this for me?

I haven't been able to find much information, most likely due to my lack of SQL knowledge, of how to even start this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to persist the `rating` average in the `links` table. I am calculating it below, and this should perform reasonably well:

```
select l.link_id,
    l.url,
    l.title,
    l.description,
    lra.AvgRating
from links l
left outer join (
    select link_id, avg(rating) as AvgRating
    from link_ratings
    group by link_id
) lra on l.link_id = lra.link_id
order by lra.AvgRating desc
```

Comment: Actually, the value I am trying to sum up and average is rating in link_ratings. Each link in the table links has many link_rating entries for it.

Comment: Awesome. This does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. One thing for clarity: l => links and lra => link_ratings right? This just substitutes the names?

Comment: @ahhchuu Yes, these are called `aliases` and can make your queries much more readable. They are also required when joining the same table more than once so that you can refer to each table seperately. (In this case `lra` is short for Link_Ratings Average).

Answer (score 1):

Proper data design would tell you to not actually store the average rating. MySQL can compute this quickly enough in most cases. Keep all of your `link_ratings` but when it comes time to display the actual ratings, join `link_ratings` to `links` and compute the average using the [MySQL `AVG()` function.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

However, if you do need to trigger each time, check out [MySQL's TRIGGER Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Something like the following untested pseudo-ish code will help you

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER UPDATE ON link_ratings
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE links
    SET links.rating = <new average>
    WHERE links.link_id = NEW.link_id;
  END;
```

Comment: I was hoping I did not need to store the average. Glad to see I don't. Thanks for the info and link. I will look into TRIGGERS yet, so when I do need them, I will understand better.